# Document method reference is not worked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I save the reference of document method:

```
let qs = document.querySelector;
```

Then try to get the element:

```
btnSort = qs('button');
```

Why does this method not work as for references to simple functions?

Comment: Because you lose the context. `querySelector` can be invoked from different elements, not just `document`, so it relies on `this`. When you reassign the reference and invoke the new variable, you lose the `this` context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this` in JavaScript is determined in runtime.

```
document.querySelector(...) // this -> document


let qs = document.querySelector

qs(...) // In this case `this` refer to the global object, which is window in a browser
```

You need to bind `this` when you created a function reference.

```
let qs = document.querySelector.bind(document)
```

Or giving a this binding when you call it.

```
qs.call(document, 'button')
```